# Game Design vs Game Development

Tags: discussion

I work as a Game Designer, where I design the game in the "paper", do all the data analytics that may need and then coordinate with the developer to create the game itself.

I came in this website for possible feedback on my questions and useful resources. However, I found it difficult since most (if not all) of the questions are related with programming.

Do you think that questions like user experience, data analytics, in-game economy etc are under the "umbrella" of Game Development or another SE proposal specifically for Game Design would be better?

I want feedback from here, so I can create the proposal if you agree with me.

Comment: Game design is on-topic as stated in the help pages: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic so you can totally ask them here, we need more non-programming questions! (I am a programmer myself =p). However a lot of game design questions might be subjective, but a lot of the topics you mentioned would have perfectly answerable questions!

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden One of the most popular questions in StackOverFlow is the collection of books and lists about C++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list. I was thinking to ask a question and then use a community wiki answer to collect case studies about specific issues. Like In-game Economy analysis or skill levels implementation or weapon features and properties. Do you think that this kind of questions would be closed? It would be a good idea to bring more traffic from Google about Game Designing

Comment: We generally only use CW questions as a last resort, so *probably* a question like that would be closed for being too broad.

Comment: kevin you should post that as an answer, so that we can upvote it and he can accept it

Answer (score 2):

There are tags for [game-design](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-design), [user-experience](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-experience), [analytics](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics), and [economy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy), and all of them contain open questions with positive scores. You could take a look to get an idea for which questions in those areas are well received.